# During design/debug process, where do files created in LocalAppData directory go?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I feel really stupid for having to ask this (I'm not a professional): during the development/design/debugging process, where do files created in the LocalAppData go? I haven't yet finished my project, so it hasn't yet been installed on any machines. Parts of my code are supposed to write information to a text file in the LocalAppData directory. However, when I run my program for testing/debugging, the text files are nowhere to be found.

```
    Dim dir As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\MyFolder\"
    Dim path As String = dir & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") & ".txt"
    If Not Directory.Exists(dir) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir)
    End If
    Using writer As New StreamWriter(path, True)
        writer.WriteLine(message)
        writer.Close()
    End Using
```

Are these files being created somewhere else? Are there special dummy folders hidden somewhere for development purposes? I tried changing the directory to Desktop and it worked. What gives?

Comment: Open a command prompt window. Type `echo %LOCALAPPDATA` and hit Enter. Or open Windows Explorer and type `%LOCALAPPDATA%` into the address bar and hit Enter. `%LOCALAPPDATA%` is a Windows folder. It's not affected by whether you're writing code, debugging, or anything else. It has nothing to do with programming; it exists on every Windows computer.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks! I actually do know how to find the folder, but it turns out I was looking in the wrong subfolder. I placed MyFolder in LocalAppData instead of nesting it inside LocalAppData/MyApplication. I feel pretty dumb right now. Thanks for trying!